# How to find the largest and smallest number in an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, max, min

I have to find a way to display the Maximum and Minium number in an array, the size of the array is 100 and will not exceed that and there is not need for input validation. The program will keep asking for input until 0 is encountered and it too will get added to the array.

I have everything figured out except how to keep track which is the largest and smallest value. I'd appreciate it if someone can fix my code or show me.Another problem I'm having is getting the loop to terminate and do max/min calculation within the while loop when the input is equal to 0.

```
/*
 ============================================================================
 Name        : test.c
 Author      :
 Version     :
 Copyright   : Your copyright notice
 Description : Hello World in C, Ansi-style
 ============================================================================
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define n  100
int main(void){


 int numbers[n];
 int i = 1;
 int j;
        int input;
 int maxvalue;
 int minvalue;

   printf("Enter the next array element>");

input = scanf("%d", &numbers[100]);



while (input != 0){

  numbers[i] = input;
  i++;
  printf("Enter the next array element, while loop>");
  input = scanf("%d", &numbers[n]);
  if (input == 0){
printf("Enter the next array element, if loop");
   numbers[i] = 0;

   for (j =2;j <= i; j++){
    minvalue = numbers[1];

    j++;
    if (numbers[j] > minvalue){
     maxvalue = numbers[j] ;
    }
    else{
     minvalue = numbers[j] ;
    }

   }


  }
 }


printf("%f\t", maxvalue);

printf("%f\n", minvalue); 
 }
```

EDIT: I took all off your suggestions and edited my code. This is my code below. However, it's output isnt what I'm expecting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N  100
int main(void){


    int numbers[N];
    int i = 0;
    int j;
        int input;
    int maxvalue;
    int minvalue;

            printf("Enter the next array element>");

scanf("%d", &input);



while (input != 0){

        numbers[i] = input;
        i++;

        if (input == 0){
                   i++;
            numbers[i] = 0;
                        minvalue = numbers[0];
                        maxvalue = numbers[0];
                        for (j=0;j<=i-1;j++){

                            if (minvalue >= numbers[j]){
                                minvalue = numbers[j];
                            }else if (maxvalue <= numbers[j]){
                                maxvalue = numbers[j];
                            }


                        }

/* min = value of first array element
max = value of first array element

begin loop for each array element, index = 0 to (n-1)

--- if array element value is less than min, set min to this value
--- if array element value is more than max, set max to this value

increment index and repeat loop til last index is completed

average = sum / number of elements (n).
max and min will hold their correct values.*/




        }
                printf("Enter the next array element, while loop>");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    }


printf("%d\t", maxvalue);
printf("%d", minvalue);
    }
```

This is the output, I'm getting! Can someone solve this for me.

```
Enter the next array element>1
Enter the next array element, while loop>2
Enter the next array element, while loop>3
Enter the next array element, while loop>0
12190144 l6Press [Enter] to close the terminal
```

FINAL EDIT: I SOLVED THIS ON MY OWN. I put the min/max checking outside the master WHILE loop, this allowed the input of 0 to be entered in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N  100
int main(void){


    int numbers[N];
    int i = 0;
    int j;
        int input;
    int maxvalue =1;
    int minvalue = 1;
            printf("Enter the next array element>");

scanf("%d", &input);
minvalue = input;
maxvalue = input;



while (input != 0){
    numbers[i] = input;

    ++i;
                printf("Enter the next array element>");
    scanf("%d", &input);

if (input == 0){
numbers[i] = 0;
  ++i;

  }

}
for (j =0;j<i;j++){
 if (numbers[j] >= maxvalue){
                                maxvalue = numbers[j];
                            }
                            if(numbers[j] < minvalue){
                                minvalue = numbers[j];
                            }

}

printf("%d\t", maxvalue);
printf("%d\n", minvalue);

    }
```

Comment: In C, array index starts at 0. You might be able to use 1 without any errors because you use it locally so you just skip first element all the time, but it will be nagging every C programmers.

Comment: Try to use uppercase for preprocessor constants like n, it shows that they are different from your variables.

Comment: Please, please, please indent your code coherently

Comment: I found this easy and useful [Code to Find the Largest and Smallest Value of an Array in C C++](http://creativesdiary.com/article/code-find-largest-and-smallest-value-array-c-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're assigning `input` to the return value of `scanf()`. This is the number of items assigned by the call, and since you say the input will always be correct, this value will always be `1`.

Secondly, you're writing past the end of the `numbers[]` array with the line:

```
input = scanf("%d", &numbers[100]);
```

(you should do `scanf("%d, &input)` instead, and assign `numbers[i]` to input in your loop.

Finally, you don't need to recalculate `maxvalue` and `minvalue` by iterating through `numbers[]` every iteration of your loop. Instead, just compare them to `input` and assign them accordingly.

Hopefully this puts you on the right track.

Comment: Your tip helped me out, but the problem now is output, its putting out unusually large numbers for some reason.

Comment: Congratulations :) I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your central problem is that you compare each number only against `minvalue`. That's fine for deciding whether to replace the current `minvalue`, but obviously it doesn't tell you anything about the relationship of each element to `maxvalue`.

Another problem: it makes sense to initialize minvalue from the first element, but not if you do it in the loop. That just invalidates all your prior work.

You need to do the same initialization with maxvalue as well. You should initialize that number to the first value.

You should also make a decision about calculating the min and max as you accumulate the data or in a pass through the data when done. What you don't want to do, however, is loop through past elements with every new one. That gives your program quadratic time complexity for no benefit.

Finally, don't tolerate crummy formatting. Debugging always involves studying the code and you will want it to always be perfectly formatted both to be professional about things and also to facilitate reading your own work.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking two questions, about the strategy for the min / max computation and for the loop. Don't do that (to yourself) but solve one problem at a time. So first put something like

```
signed int input[] = { 8, -5 , /* some more values */ };
size_t const n = sizeof input/ sizeof input[0];
```

at the start and forget about your `scanf` problems.

Then wrap your min/max detection in the appropriate loop instruction.

Then compile your code with warnings on: e.g `-Wall` for `gcc`, but this might vary for your compiler.

Mine the tells me something:

> test-numbers.c:21: warning: 'maxvalue'
>   may be used uninitialized in this
>   function test-numbers.c:22: warning:
>   'minvalue' may be used uninitialized
>   in this function

This tells you that you are doing something very wrong in not considering the starting point of your algorithm well.

Answer (score 0):

I've reindented your code and replaced lots of it with `/* ...PLACEHOLDER... */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N  100
int main(void) {
    int numbers[N];
    int i = 0;
    int input;
    int maxvalue;
    int minvalue;

    printf("Enter the next array element>");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    while (input != 0) {
        numbers[i] = input;
        i++;

        if (input == 0) {
            /* ...PLACEHOLDER... */
        }
        printf("Enter the next array element, while loop>");
        scanf("%d", &input);
    }
    printf("%d\t", maxvalue);
    printf("%d", minvalue);
}
```

Hopefully you can see what happens when you enter 1, or 2, or 3 and when you enetr 0.

Hint: `maxvalue` and `minvalue` values are never changed.

Another hint: how many times does the `while()` line execute?

---

**Edit** with example run

For this example run, code is on the left side, what happens is on the left side

```
        printf("Enter the next array element>"); |
        scanf("%d", &input);                     | Enter 42
                                                 |
        while (input != 0) {                     | input is 42, so you do the loop
            numbers[i] = input;                  | numbers[0] = 42
            i++;                                 | i = 1
                                                 |
            if (input == 0) {                    | input != 0; skip placeholder
                /* ...PLACEHOLDER... */          |
            }                                    |
            printf("Enter the next ...>");       |
            scanf("%d", &input);                 | enter 3
        }                                        | 
        while (input != 0) {                     | input is 3
            numbers[i] = input;                  | numbers[1] = 3
            i++;                                 | i = 2
                                                 |
            if (input == 0) {                    | input != 0; skip placeholder
                /* ...PLACEHOLDER... */          |
            }                                    |
            printf("Enter the next ...>");       |
            scanf("%d", &input);                 | enter 0
        }                                        | 
        while (input != 0) {                     | input is 0, skip while body
            /* ...PLACEHOLDER... */              |
        }                                        |
        printf("%d\t", maxvalue);                | maxvalue hasn't been initialized
        printf("%d", minvalue);                  | minvalue hasn't been changed
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to show me. How doesn't the min/max value change values?

Answer (score -3):

```
int cmp(const void *a,const void *b)
{
  return *(const int*)a-*(const int*)b;
}
...
qsort( numbers, 100, sizeof(numbers[0]), cmp );
printf("\nmin: %d\nmax: %d",numbers[0],numbers[99]);
```

Comment: -1 The input stops at 0. There is no certainty there will be 100 elements in the array. *And why do you feel `qsort()` is a good choice for the OP?*

Comment: Wow this has to be the most inefficient method of finding a min and max ever, not to mention all the other problems. (OK, I'm exaggerating a little bit, but still, O(n log n) versus O(n) is pretty sucky.)

Comment: @Domenic: while I agree this method is ridiculously inefficient, `O(n log n)` and `O(n)` might as well be the same when `n` fits in a machine word. 32 (or 64) is a pretty small constant. And if it doesn't fit in a machine word, then incrementing the position counter in the data for a "linear search" is an `O(log n)` operation, making the whole task `O(n log n)`.. :-)

Comment: While speed wasn't an issue in this. Qsort wasn't a good match, because our teacher doesn't want using stuff we haven't learned. I have added the code above which is finally working.

Comment: "speed wasn't an issue in this", but mr.pmg only like solutions in his added issues.